# Multiple UILocalNotifications

Tags: objective-c, json, uilocalnotification

I am trying to create multiple UILocalNotifications. I am able to create 1 notification at a time, but what about when I want to create multiple notifications at the same time and each one with different fire dates etc. Now, you sure, that can be easy to do but the issue is that the notification numbers are not consistent. I can have 4, and then another one will have 6 or 7 notifications that need to be created at the same time. So is more like a dynamic list. I am using JSON to get the UTC time for each and thats what I use to fire them but I can have multiple UTC dates to be added into a UILocalNotification from JSON. Does that makes sense? Let me know and I can try to explain better. Is there any approach to this?

This is the code I use:

```
   UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = notificationNSDate;
localNotification.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newsArticleTitle];
localNotification.alertAction = @"open";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

notificationNSDate, is the UTC date value. This is how I convert it from JSON:

```
        dicToString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newsArticleTwo];
        notificationTimeString =  dicToString;
        notificationArrat = [notificationTimeString componentsSeparatedByString:@"T"];
        mainNotificationCalendarDate = [notificationArrat objectAtIndex:0];
        mainNotificationTimeString = [notificationArrat objectAtIndex:1];
        timeArray = [mainNotificationTimeString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
        mainNotificationTime = [timeArray objectAtIndex:0];
        timeArrayCorrected = [mainNotificationTime componentsSeparatedByString:@"Z"];
        mainNotificationTimeCorrected = [timeArrayCorrected objectAtIndex:0];
        fullDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",mainNotificationCalendarDate,mainNotificationTimeCorrected];
        dateString = fullDate;
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        notificationNSDate = [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*240];
```

**newsArticleTwo**: Is a NSDictionary which I pass from a different viewController:

```
 svc.newsArticleTwo = [newsArticle objectForKey:@"UTCDateTime"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can create and schedule up to 64 local notifications.

Comment: My problem is that I need help on creating multiple notifications dynamically. If there where always 3 notifications to create, sure! No problem. But it varies. Sometimes it can be 3, and sometime is can be 5, 6 , 7, etc. The number of notifications to be created is not consistent.

Comment: Show the JSON and the code you've tried so far

Comment: Presumably there is some JSON that you need to iterate over? I'm not getting what it is that you don't understand. You have code to parse dates and create notifications. A loop required for JSON processing?